# Player not moved after android build

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games, android-build

Hi everyone I'm newbie in unity and I'm starting my first project in 2d game. This game is endless runner. player is running and user can drag & drop to change his position. Also using random scrolling background. everything is fine in Unity Remote 4 but after build for android and install the final APK player just running and drag and drop not working. Any solution to fix this bug would helped me.

Thanks.

Comment: This would depend entirely on your code, which you haven't provided.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant code and Android log so we can figure out what is happening?